# Home folder has limit on size, how to remove it?

Tags: home-directory, disk-usage

How to understand that picture? home 6.4% and user folder 100%

[image: home folder]

Comment: We need more details. From the screenshot, it looks like you might be running on a live CD. Is that correct? If not, is the home folder on a separate partition? Please add the results of running `df -h` to your post. The out of `mount` might also be helpful, depending. Finally, have you enabled quotas?

Comment: i have a folder target, that looks like my installation was broken

Comment: ??? I don't understand. What's a folder target? And the other info will help in any case.

Answer (score 2):

Your picture just shows us that your `ubuntu` folder accounts for 100% of the `home` folder size which is the expected behavior if you only have one account on this setup. That has nothing to do with quotas or size limits.

Comment: Drat. I forgot how Baobab works.

Comment: I must agree the presentation is a bit misleading!